# Having an issue with Subforms and variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form which I dynamically create based on a config file and I followed the sample on https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. What causes me some issues is how i can set a value for a var like

```
hideAgent: boolean = false
```

in my template code i use the folowing

```
<!-- Text Box Input -->
<div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'">
    <div *ngIf="hideAgent === false"  class="visitor-info-input-row">
        <div class="input-label">{{question.label}}</div>
        <input type="text" [name]="question.key" value="test Value" [placeholder]="hideAgent" [formControlName]="question.key" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
    </div></div>
```

Based on what I set the initial value to, it will show or hide the text . But when i use some code to toggle between true or false it does not work. to make it simple i just check what the value of this.hideAgent is and set it to the opposite. The code for this is

```
 myFunction(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    if(this.hideAgent === true){
      this.hideAgent = false;
    } else {
           this.hideAgent = true;
      }
  }
```

when doing so the {{hideAgent}} on the control which i use to toggle show the correct value, the values at the bottom of form or inside the textbox never change only the initial value set when the page is init is show.

So my question is what do i need to do that any control that looks at {{hideAgent}} sees the correct value ?

Comment: From where and how are you calling `myFunction()` otherwise the code looks fine. Please share rest of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `OnPush` change detection strategy and if `hideAgent` is not an `@Input`, then you need to force change detection manually when you change the value ([this API reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) page has few examples of how to do it).

Another possible reason is that `myFunction` is called outside of `NgZone` which does not trigger change detection, and in this case you need to wrap the call to that function with `NgZone#run()` call (here is [another API reference page](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) with example).